# Problem with javafx application resulting in "cannot be resolved" error messages?

Tags: java, javafx

I installed javafx today for an assignment but I am running into problems now that I'm trying to write code. I installed javafx through the help category on eclipse as that is what some videos online said to do. I know I am running a javafx project because when creating the project I went to "other" and clicked on the javafx project tab. Now though I am just getting error messages like "the import java.fx.application could not be resolved". And this is happening for all the imports I put into the project. Here is some of my code that I inputted into eclipse which has resulted in error messages.

```
import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;

import javafx.scene.Scene;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

int SIZE = 10;

int length = SIZE;

int width = SIZE;

GridPane root = new GridPane();

for(int y = 0; y < length; y++){

for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){

Random rand = new Random();

int rand1 = rand.nextInt(100);
```

Comment: I've always wondered where these double-spaced code examples come from. Is your IDE or whatever configured to double-space your code? Or is it some issue with whatever method you used to copy-and-paste your code? Because, in my opinion, double-spaced code is horrendous to read and I don't understand why anyone would want that. In this case, it also doesn't help that all indenting has been erased...

Comment: In any case, what version of Java and JavaFX are you using? What operating system? What Java distribution? Have you seen https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/?

Answer (score 0):

You must add

--module-path "your path to JavaFX here" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

into your VM arguments.

To do this:

1. right click on your main java file
2. Select run -> run configurations
3. Go to tab Arguments
4. Paste above with your specific path to where you installed javaFX